# dismiss view controller custom animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to replicate this animation to dismiss a view controller (15 second video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u87thAbT0CQ

This is what my animation looks like so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2XmXTVxLdw

This is my code for the pan gesture recognizer:

```
 @IBAction func recognizerDragged(sender: AnyObject) {
    let displacement = recognizer.translationInView(view)
    view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x + displacement.x, view.center.y + displacement.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, inView: view)
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Ended:
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)
        })
    default:
        print("default")
    }

    let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.titleView)
    print(velocity)
    if velocity.y < -1500 {
        up = true
      self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    if velocity.x > 1500 {
        right = true
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It may be a little hard to notice in my video, but there is a small disconnect in how fast the user flicks up, and how fast the animation completes. That is to say, the user may flip up very fast but the animation is set to a hardcoded 0.3 seconds. So if the user flicks the view fast, then as the animation completes, as soon as their finger lifts off the view, the animation actually slows down.

I think what I need is a way to take the velocity recorded in the recognizerDragged IBAction, and pass that to the animation controller, and based on that, calculate how long the animation should take, so that the velocity is consistent throughout, and it looks smooth. How can I do that?

Additioanlly, I'm slightly confused because the Apple Documentation says that the velocityInView function returns a velocity in points, not pixels. Yet different iOS devices have different points per pixels, so that would further complicate how I would translate the velocity before passing it to the animation class.

Any idea how to pass the velocity back to the animation controller, so that the animation duration changes based on that, and make it work for different iPhones ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you are likely looking at in the video you are trying to replicate is a UIDynamics style interaction, not a CoreAnimation animation. The velocity returned from velocityInView can be used directly in UIDynamics like this:

```
[self.behavior addLinearVelocity:
        [pan velocityInView:pan.view.superview] forItem:pan.view];
```

I wrote a tutorial for doing this style of view interaction here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/ios7-new-dynamic-app-interactions/

To stick with UIView animations you just need to look at the frame's bottom  (which is also in points) and calculate the new time. This assume that you want frame's bottom to be at 0 at the end of the animation:

```
  animationTime = CGRectGetMaxY(frame) / velocity
```

You aren't showing how you created the animation controller, but just keep a reference to it and pass the time before calling dismiss.  This is also assuming you are using a linear curve.  With any other kind of curve, you will have to estimate what the starting velocity would have to be to be based on time and adjust.